# Copying drive with windows installation under Ubuntu 18

Tags: boot, windows-10, copy

I got a virus on my computer Win 10. So I decided to do full reinstall. To save files I installed new hard drive, created USB Ubuntu stick, booted from it and I am trying to copy files under Ubuntu. I am getting the following error message while copying:

```
Error while copying
There was an error reading folder "LocalCache"
Error opening directory 
 '/media/ubuntu/CCB411EEB411DC30/Users/some_user/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c/LocalCache': No such file or directory
```

There are options to cancel, skip all, skip and retry

Retry does not work, but I can always skip. 
But I curious where this error is coming from and how to fix it?

**Update 1:** 
I found the problem file/folder on the original drive. Here is some info on it.

```
Name: LocalCache
Type: Link (broken) (inode/symlink)
Link target: unsupported reparse point
Size: 25 bytes
```

**Update 2:**

Running terminal `stat` command on this file returned:

```
File: LocalCache -> unsupported reparse point
  Size: 25          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   symbolic link
Device: 824h/2084d  Inode: 918487      Links: 2
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  999/  ubuntu)   Gid: (  999/  ubuntu)
Access: 2019-02-24 00:33:56.728640800 +0000
Modify: 2018-10-30 17:29:05.927748100 +0000
Change: 2018-10-30 17:29:05.927748100 +0000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the actual file is (& directory in which it resides); ie. what is in that directory?  If you see the file, what type (`file`) of file is it? can you `stat` it?  to view attributes for clues etc.  If you're happy with keeping it I'd them `mv` or `rename` it to rename it IF i believed it safe & wanted; otherwise I'd just `rm` it & restore a backup. *these are random thoughts - I alter where I go by what I see in prior step...*

Comment: @guiverc, Thank you for reply! I added update. I am not even sure if it is file or folder. I would rather keep it if possible.

Comment: the commands used do not change if it's a file or folder.  `file` would have reported it's a folder if you'd use that (file is a command to determine file type [*using contents of file and not it's name*])   I'd also suggest when you copy/paste output you provide context (ie. command used to create output; you saw the command, we didn't & may make false assumptions...)

Comment: @guiverc Sorry I did not clarify, I am copying them using standard Ubuntu GUI, I do not remember proper name of it

Comment: @guiverc, I added `stat` command output to question

Comment: Okay, I use command usually (not `nautilus` which is probably what you're using). It's not a real file, but a file-entry pointing to a inode (block/cluster) used by another file ... `stat` would have provided this info (i'm used to looking at command line). Since it's not a Ubuntu fs, it may not see everything windows sees, but I'd skip it (you could manually `ln -s` it later, but to be useful in windows it would need to be done within windows.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, (and Linux in general), Windows NTFS file systems are handled by the ntfs-3g driver.

In Windows 10, Microsoft introduced new kinds of "reparse points", which that driver cannot process.

I would recommend reading this: https://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/advanced-ntfs-3g.html

and installing the "system compression" and the "deduplicated files" plugins.

It's interesting - please tell us whether it helped.